# Colors of fonts in package manager console with posh-git?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, posh-git

I'm trying to get the package manager console to look exactly like a standalone powershell console with posh-git. The only thing i've been unable to replicate is the red font used for files. Here is my package manager console:

[image]

and here is my powershell console:

[image]

Does anyone replicate that functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a limitation of the Package Manager Console. Git.exe renders colors using [Bash color escape sequences](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html), which seem to be ignored by PMC.

Unrelated: it's curious that PMC uses 8-character tabs but the normal PowerShell host uses 4.

Comment: thanks this will save me time i'm trying to find a solution :)